# Reading S3 bucket objects

Tags: pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an S3 bucket created which contains multiple json objects. I want to read all these objects in once and put them in pandas dataframe.

Comment: you won't be able to read them at once, but you can concat all the objects once you have them inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries out there that can help you with that, as well as many articles that talk about reading from S3. Start there. I recommend using the [boto3 library](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/) since there are so many articles like [this one](https://hands-on.cloud/working-with-s3-in-python-using-boto3/) that use this library to do what you want while giving you a pretty comprehensive overview of the tool. Specially check out the `How to get a list of files from S3 Bucket?` section for what you want. Once you have the objects assigned to a local variable, assigning them to a dataframe should be simple.

In any case, once you have done some implementation and hit a blocker, then post here on SO so that we can help with more specific points.